# How do I draw shapes that can change from compile to compile in java

Tags: java

I'm making a simple mastermind game where you try and guess the code. I almost have everything set up, but I need to draw the shapes to the screen where they would normally go in the game. This is what I have so far...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Start {

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Window ex = new Window();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        Object[] possibilities = { "Start", "Quit" };
        String menu = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Welcome to Mastermind. Select and option and enjoy the Game!\"", "Start Menu", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities, "Yes");

        switch (menu) {
        case "Start":
            Load l = new Load();
            l.load();
        case "Exit":
            System.exit(0);
        case "Cancel":
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Load class and nevermind the messed up formatting.

```
 import java.util.Random;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Load {

        private JFrame frame;

        public Load() {
        }
        public void load() {

            boolean t1Place = false;
            boolean t2Place = false;
            boolean t3Place = false;
            boolean t4Place = false;

            // Generate colors
            Random rand = new Random();
            int cId1 = rand.nextInt(6);
            int cId2 = rand.nextInt(6);
            int cId3 = rand.nextInt(6);
            int cId4 = rand.nextInt(6);

            String c1 = null, c2 = null, c3 = null, c4 = null;

            switch (cId1) {
            case 0:
                c1 = "Red";
                break;
            case 1:
                c1 = "Blue";
                break;
            case 2:
                c1 = "Black";
                break;
            case 3:
                c1 = "Green";
                break;
            case 4:
                c1 = "White";
                break;
            case 5:
                c1 = "Orange";
                break;
            }
            switch (cId2) {
            case 0:
                c2 = "Red";
                break;
            case 1:
                c2 = "Blue";
                break;
            case 2:
                c2 = "Black";
                break;
            case 3:
                c2 = "Green";
                break;
            case 4:
                c2 = "White";
                break;
            case 5:
                c2 = "Orange";
                break;
            }
            switch (cId3) {
            case 0:
                c3 = "Red";
                break;
            case 1:
                c3 = "Blue";
                break;
            case 2:
                c3 = "Black";
                break;
            case 3:
                c3 = "Green";
                break;
            case 4:
                c3 = "White";
                break;
            case 5:
                c3 = "Orange";
                break;
            }
            switch (cId4) {
            case 0:
                c4 = "Red";
                break;
            case 1:
                c4 = "Blue";
                break;
            case 2:
                c4 = "Black";
                break;
            case 3:
                c4 = "Green";
                break;
            case 4:
                c4 = "White";
                break;
            case 5:
                c4 = "Orange";
                break;
            }
            //passing variables through

            Game game = new Game(c1, c2, c3, c4, t1Place, t2Place, t3Place, t4Place);
        }
    }
```

game class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JFrame frame;



    int loopCount = 1;

    public Game(String c1, String c2, String c3, String c4, boolean t1Place, boolean t2Place, boolean t3Place, boolean t4Place) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Object[] possibilities1 = { "Blue", "Red", "Black", "Green", "White", "Orange" };
            String color1 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Select your first color:\"", "1st Color", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities1, "Blue");
            repaint();
            Object[] possibilities2 = { "Blue", "Red", "Black", "Green", "White", "Orange" };
            String color2 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Select your first color:\"", "2nd Color", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities2, "Blue");

            Object[] possibilities3 = { "Blue", "Red", "Black", "Green", "White", "Orange" };
            String color3 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Select your first color:\"", "3rd Color", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities3, "Blue");

            Object[] possibilities4 = { "Blue", "Red", "Black", "Green", "White", "Orange" };
            String color4 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Select your first color:\"", "4th Color", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities4, "Blue");

            //testing if its there
            if(c1.equals(color1)) {
                t1Place = true;
            }
            if(c2.equals(color2)){
                t2Place = true;
            }
            if(c3.equals(color3)) {
                t3Place = true;
            }
            if(c4.equals(color4)) {
                t4Place = true;
            }





            String all = c1 += c2 += c3 += c4;
            String tAll = color1 += color2 += color3 += color4;
            if (all.equals(tAll)) {
                win();
                System.exit(0);
            }

        loopCount++;
    }
        Object[] possibilities = { "Yes", "No" };
        String cont = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "You lost. Continue?\"", "Continue?",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities, "Yes");

        if (cont == "Yes") {
            Load l = new Load();
            l.load();
        }
        if (cont == "No") {
            System.exit(0);
        }
}

    public void win() {
        Object[] contin = { "Yes", "No" };
        String cont = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "You Won! Play Again?\"", "WINNER", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, contin, "Yes");

        if (cont == "Yes") {
            Load l1 = new Load();
            l1.load();
        }
        if (cont == "No") {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


    public Game() {
    }
}
```

Graphics class

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Graphics extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //draw the board
    public void drawBoard(java.awt.Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawRect(10, 10, 470, 640);//main rect.

        //sides
        g2d.drawRect(10, 10, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 74, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 138, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 202, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 266, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 330, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 394, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 458, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 522, 128, 64);
        g2d.drawRect(10, 586, 128, 64);

        //dots
        g2d.drawOval(174, 42, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 42, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 42, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 42, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 106, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 106, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 106, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 106, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 170, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 170, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 170, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 170, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 234, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 234, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 234, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 234, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 298, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 298, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 298, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 298, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 362, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 362, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 362, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 362, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 426, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 426, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 426, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 426, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 490, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 490, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 490, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 490, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 554, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 554, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 554, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 554, 10, 10);

        g2d.drawOval(174, 618, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(260, 618, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(346, 618, 10, 10);
        g2d.drawOval(432, 618, 10, 10);


    }



      public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            drawBoard(g);
      }       

}
```

window class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Window() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        add(new Graphics());

        setTitle("Mastermind");
        setSize(500, 700);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


}
```

I'm kind of a noob lol. I figured out how to draw the main board but I can't draw the dots onto it when they get inputed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain your code and clarify your question. Also as a side rec: don't give your classes names that clash with key Java classes, like Graphics as that can mess you up royal down the road.

Comment: Start class is just a start menu. It brings up the window where the actual game is and says start or quit. The load class generates a random code and sets some booleans to say if the colors guessed are in the right place later on. Game class has you input the colors that you guess and sees if the two codes match--it will tell you if they do match.Graphics class(ty for the tip) draws a screen that looks like a mastermind board. Window class brings up a window. I can't figure out how to display the correctly colored dots on the screen when they are inputed.

Comment: http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/blogs/geekmom/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Game.png This is a link to a mastermind board picture

Comment: When you create a GUI, the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) helps you separate your concerns and focus on one piece of the GUI at a time.  Create model classes to hold the game state and draw the view using the model information.

Answer (score 1):

Myself, I'd avoid using "magic" numbers to draw the whole grid as you're doing, but rather subdivide the work into smaller components, perhaps a JPanel to hold each row, and compose each row of dots as a grid of JLabels held by a GridLayout using JPanel, and then simply swap ImageIcons for when I want to display dot colors.

Or if you want to draw the colors, then simply fill in the ovals that you have using `Graphics#fillOval(...)`. But if you do either, you need to easily know the logical location of the oval (row and column) and have it correlate with a physical location on your image, something not easy to do.

As a side recommendations:

- don't give your classes names that clash with key Java classes, like Graphics as that can mess you up royal down the road.
- Don't compare Strings with `==` or `!=` such as: `if (cont == "Yes") {`. Instead use the `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method. `==` compares object references, something you're not interested in while the methods check if the Strings have the same chars in the same order -- what you *are* interested in.

One way to allow the user to select colors is to give your component a MouseListener and cycle through the colors on mouse pressed. You could perhaps only allow this to occur if the row were "active" that is the next row in the set. Something like this could work:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class QuickMasterMind extends JPanel {
    private GridPanel gridPanel = new GridPanel();
    private int activeRowIndex = 0;

    public QuickMasterMind() {
        gridPanel.getRow(activeRowIndex).setActive(true);

        JButton submitRowBtn = new JButton(new SubmitRowAction("Submit Row"));
        JButton resetBtn = new JButton(new ResetAction("Reset"));
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(submitRowBtn);
        btnPanel.add(resetBtn);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    private class ResetAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ResetAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gridPanel.reset();
            activeRowIndex = 0;
            gridPanel.getRow(activeRowIndex).setActive(true);
        }
    }

    private class SubmitRowAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SubmitRowAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            RowPanel activeRow = gridPanel.getRow(activeRowIndex);
            if (!activeRow.areAllSelected()) {
                Object message = "All row colors must be set before submitting row";
                String title = "Submit Row Error";
                int messageType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(activeRow, message, title, messageType);
                return;
            }
            gridPanel.getRow(activeRowIndex).setActive(false);

            // TODO: more code to check to see how many colors are correct
            // and to display somewhere else

            activeRowIndex++;
            if (activeRowIndex < GridPanel.ROW_COUNT) {
                gridPanel.getRow(activeRowIndex).setActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("QuickMasterMind");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new QuickMasterMind());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GridPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final int ROW_COUNT = 10;
    private RowPanel[] rows = new RowPanel[ROW_COUNT];

    public GridPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i] = new RowPanel();
            add(rows[i]);
        }
    }

    public RowPanel getRow(int row) {
        return rows[row];
    }

    public void reset() {
        for (RowPanel rowPanel : rows) {
            rowPanel.reset();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class RowPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final int CELL_COUNT = 4;
    Cell[] cells = new Cell[CELL_COUNT];

    public RowPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i] = new Cell();
            add(cells[i]);
        }
    }

    public boolean areAllSelected() {
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            if (cell.getMyColor() == MyColor.EMPTY) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            cell.setActive(active);
        }
    }

    public MyColor getCellColor(int column) {
        return cells[column].getMyColor();
    }

    public void reset() {
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            cell.reset();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Cell extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private static final int PREF_W = 50;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static Map<MyColor, Icon> iconMap = new EnumMap<>(MyColor.class);
    static {
        int w = PREF_W;
        int h = PREF_H;
        int imgType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        for (MyColor myColor : MyColor.values()) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, imgType);
            Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
            g2.setColor(myColor.getColor());
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.fillOval(GAP, GAP, w - 2 * GAP, h - 2 * GAP);
            g2.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4f));
            g2.drawOval(GAP, GAP, w - 2 * GAP, h - 2 * GAP);
            g2.dispose();
            iconMap.put(myColor, new ImageIcon(img));
        }
    }
    private MyColor myColor = MyColor.EMPTY;
    private boolean active = false;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel(iconMap.get(myColor));

    public Cell() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        label.addMouseListener(new LabelListener());
    }

    public MyColor getMyColor() {
        return myColor;
    }

    public void setMyColor(MyColor myColor) {
        this.myColor = myColor;
        label.setIcon(iconMap.get(myColor));
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public void reset() {
        setMyColor(MyColor.EMPTY);
        active = false;
    }

    private class LabelListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!active) {
                return;
            }

            int index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < MyColor.values().length; i++) {
                if (MyColor.values()[i] == myColor) {
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            index++;
            index %= MyColor.values().length;
            setMyColor(MyColor.values()[index]);
        }
    }

}

enum MyColor {
    BLUE(Color.BLUE, "Blue"), RED(Color.RED, "Red"), 
    BLACK(Color.BLACK, "Black"), GREEN(Color.GREEN, "Green"), 
    WHITE(Color.WHITE, "White"), ORANGE(Color.ORANGE, "Orange"), 
    EMPTY(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0), "Empty");

    private Color color;
    private String name;

    private MyColor(Color color, String name) {
        this.color = color;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can just feel the pain it must have been to write it this way. +1